# Multiple Camera Providers for Azure Media Services

Tags: ios, windows-mobile, webcam, azure-media-services

We are commissioning a website which will allow individuals to stream content from their PC's to global audiences.  We are investigating if Azure Media Services offers the widest features to support content providers with mixtures of mobile devices, Mac and PC systems on a global scale.

We are looking at a charging model for end users who pay per minute whilst watching content providers.

Is it technically possibly to have a few thousand content streams being broadcast simultaneously still utilising the Azure pricing model.

Kind regards

James

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's definitely possible with Azure Media Services. We have live streamed many large scale events such as World Cup and Olympics. We offer VOD streaming to customers like Blinkbox. Our stream gets dynamically packaged into Smooth Streaming, HLS and DASH, which can be consumed by various devices and platforms.

From a pricing perspective, we charge you encoding, media storage. And $199 for streaming server with guaranteed bandwidth. You can further charge your users on per minutes viewing (this you have to track on your player side).